# Cygwin - gcc-java installed but cannot call

Tags: gcc, cygwin

I'm running Cygwin on Windows 7, with environment variables set up correctly (as far as I can tell).

When I do this `gcc-java` shows up:

```
cygcheck-c
..
gcc-core             3.4.4-999            OK
gcc-g++              3.4.4-999            OK
gcc-java             3.4.4-999            OK <---
gcc-mingw-core       20050522-3           OK
..
```

When I call `gcc-java`, I get a command not found error. In `C:\cygwin\bin` the `gcc-java` binary is not there, yet it claims to be installed (tried reinstalling). I can call all other commands in `\bin\`

Answer (score 0):

There is no `gcc-java` binary; the compiler is named `gcj`.  BTW, you want to install the `gcc4-java` instead; it provides a more recent version.